# Загрузка фоток в фотоальбом

Tags: php, mysql

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться. Делаю фотоальбомы. Альбомы создаются нормально. Потом надо выбирать альбом из select, выбирать фотку и загружать. Так вот, проблема в том, что при выборе любого альбома фотки загружаются в один. Есть таблица в бд `albom`, в ней содержатся поля `id_albom` (`auto_increment`), `id` (ему присваивается `id` юзера), `albom` (туда заносится название альбома, когда создаёшь) и `id_albom1` (туда тоже заносится название альбома при создании, знаю оно не надо). И есть таблица photos, в ней поля: `id_photo`(`auto_increment`), `id` (ему присваивается `id` юзера), `photo` (имя фотки) и `albom` (сюда должен вставляться альбом который выбрал из `select`, но вставляется один и тот же). А вот сам запрос в файле обработчике:

```
$q1 = mysql_query("select * from albom where id='$myrow2[id]'");
$q2 = mysql_fetch_array($q1);

$result31 = mysql_query("INSERT INTO photos (id,photo,albom) VALUES ('$myrow2[id]','$filename','$q2[albom]')",$db);`
```

надо как-то указать, чтоб фотка грузилась в выбранный альбом, но что-то не понимаю как.

Answer (score 1):

проблема в том что у тебя не передается этот самый

```
 $q2[albom]
```

Попробуй в форме на добавление фотки добавить скрытое поле для этого.

Comment: Как вариант еще albom в кавычки заключить.